# Optimise R Code - Sampling returns from S&P500 series

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to see how "winning percentage" affects returns for a trading strategy.

I download the prices of S&P and calculating the daily returns.  Then, I randomly select x% of these returns and say I correctly predicted it's direction so the return is positive.  For the remainder 1-x%, I say I am wrong and the return is negative.  I replicate this process say 1000 times and collect the annualised geometric return.

I vary x from 0.5 to 0.6 at 0.01 increment intervals.

Here is my code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(multicore)

getSymbols("^GSPC", from = "1950-1-1")
ret <- ROC(GSPC)[-1,4]

set.seed(123)

winpct <- seq(0.5, 0.6, 0.01)
ret <- coredata(ret)

system.time(res <- simplify2array(mclapply(winpct, function(x) replicate(1000, drawsample(ret, x)))))

drawsample <- function(ret, winpct){
  len = length(ret)
  ret = abs(ret)

  win = sample(1:len, round(winpct * len))
  a = c(ret[win], -ret[-win])
  return(prod(1 + a) ^ (252 / length(a)) - 1)
}
```

Time taken:

```
   user  system elapsed 
 18.904   0.842   5.580
```

Are there any further optimisations I can do to speed things up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made the following two tweaks:

1/ use `exp(sum(a))` rather than `prod(1+a)`. I think you want this anyways, as you have created a log returns series with `ROC(GSPC)[-1,6]`. According to `rbenchmark` this got me a speedup of about 7%.

2/ sample from `c(-1,-1)` for the length of the `ret` series, and then multiply with the ret series, to obtain the signed series of returns.  This got me another 30%.

Note that in my code, i've re-named your `a` as `bin`.

```
drawsample2 <- function(ret, winpct){
  len = length(ret)
  win = sample(c(-1,1), len, replace=TRUE, prob = c((1-winpct), winpct))
  ret <- abs(ret)
  bin <- ret*win
  return(exp(sum(bin))^(252/length(ret)) - 1)
}
```

Benchmarking against your `drawsample()` i get ~37% speedup.

```
bb <- benchmark(simplify2array(mclapply(winpct, function(x) replicate(1000, drawsample(ret, x)))), 
          simplify2array(mclapply(winpct, function(x) replicate(1000, drawsample2(ret, x)))),
          columns =c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative'),
          replications = 10,
          order = 'elapsed')
```

On my MBP, here are the benchmarks:

```
> bb

  elapsed relative
2  17.254    1.000
1  27.734    1.607
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tweak of [ricardo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453172/ricardo) function that is faster for larger objects.  I removed the calls to `mclapply` in order to isolate the performance of the functions by avoiding the network overhead required by multi-core processing.

```
drawsample_r <- function(ret, winpct){
  len = length(ret)
  win = sample(c(-1,1), len, replace=TRUE, prob = c((1-winpct), winpct))
  ret <- abs(ret)
  bin <- ret*win
  return(exp(sum(bin))^(252/length(ret)) - 1)
}
drawsample_j <- function(ret, winpct){
  len <- length(ret)
  win <- c(-1L,1L)[sample.int(2L,len,TRUE,c(1-winpct,winpct))]
  exp(sum(abs(ret)*win))^(252L/len)-1L
}
library(rbenchmark)
set.seed(123)
ret <- rnorm(1e6)/100  # 1 million observations
winpct <- seq(0.5, 0.6, 0.01)
benchmark(sapply(winpct, drawsample_r, ret=ret),
          sapply(winpct, drawsample_j, ret=ret),
  replications=10, order='elapsed')[,1:5]
#                                    test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 2 sapply(winpct, drawsample_j, ret=ret)           10   6.963    1.000     6.956
# 1 sapply(winpct, drawsample_r, ret=ret)           10  10.852    1.559    10.689
```

Comment: +1. that's a very nice tweak. Does explicitly using integers speed things up in general?

Comment: @ricardo: yes, integers are a lot faster than doubles for large vectors where RAM speed becomes a bottleneck.  In this case, they help the most when creating `win`; I doubt converting to integer in the last line has much impact.